# XML 2.0 RSS Feeds Processing Android

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, saxparser

Have a look at the [feed here](http://www.style.com/homepage/rss). It is easy to process XML 1.0 / 1.1 where they only have normal characters in the `<description>` tag. However, the RSS feed mentioned above has HTML tags like `<strong>`, `<em>`, etc and not to mention, `JavaScript` function calls and special characters.

What I, as a beginner to Android, do is to make my own SAX parser to get the data from specific tags, put them into objects that represent feeds and make an `ArrayList` / `Vector` out of them. All I get is character data in the `characters(..)` callback method of `DefaultHandler`.

**Now, how do I properly display this text with all the HTML formatting, the `JavaScript` function calls, etc in Android?**

I mean, the one who made the RSS feeds for this put it all this in because they wanted the feeds to hav a certain look-and-feel. Please help me with this.

Comment: *Update* I know XML 2.0 is not official but since it is in the feeds, I decided to put it in the title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel..

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android),use  [android-rss](https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss) library to read parts of RSS 2.0 feeds.I have used it in my project and it works brilliantly..

```
  RSSReader reader = new RSSReader();
  RSSFeed feed = reader.load(feedUrl);
  List<RSSItem> list = feed.getItems();
  for (RSSItem i: list) 
  {
    i.getTitle();//title content
    i.getDescription();//description content
    i.getLink();//link
  }
```

---

To view the description content use [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) which would return styled text..

```
TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(descriptionContent));
```

Comment: This sounds so cool !! Get the description, put it into the `WebView` and tada!!